# Big Bottom Padding of Text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem with big bottom padding of text in EditText.This only Happens in Gingerbread and lower ROMs. In ICS and up it is all okay.
Here´s what i mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BisvZ.jpg

Here´s the EditText´s Code:

```
                   <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/height2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/diag"
                    android:digits="1234567890."
                    android:minWidth="80dp"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned" />
```

As you can see there is no padding set for Text.
The Custom Layout xml:

```
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_default_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_activated_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_default_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:state_multiline="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_holo_light" />

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_light" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_activated_holo_light" />
<iten android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_light" />
```

Comment: That's not a standard look and feel for an `EditText` widget "in Gingerbread and lower ROMs". If you want to roll with that, I'd start with HoloEverywhere. Personally, I'd use a different style for the older devices, one that resembles what the users are used to.

Comment: Actually that was just an temporary EditText style, the actual one would not look like that :P (Alike, But not ICS style)